# Import XML for Google Sheets to import single value

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use importxml to import the "52 Week Avg Return" number (in this case it is -10.02%) on this website: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vwelx

I'm not sure what to add to this formula to correct it. Any help would be appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUnIl.jpg)

I am using this formula:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vwelx", "//span[@class='primary']")

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following XPath?

#### Sample XPath:

```
//li[@class='kv__item' and ./small[text()='52 Week Avg Return']]/span
```

or

```
//li[@class='kv__item' and position()=last()]/span
```

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//li[@class='kv__item' and ./small[text()='52 Week Avg Return']]/span")
```

or

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//li[@class='kv__item' and position()=last()]/span")
```

- In this case, please set the URL of `https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vwelx` to the cell "A1".

#### Testing:

[image]

#### Note:

- This XPath is for your provided URL of `https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vwelx`. So, when you change the URL, this might not be able to be used. And also, when the specification of the server side is changed, this might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: @Drew Culross About `Wow perfect, thank you so much!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: it does not allow me yet to accept but I will check in again in a few days and do so if available.